# MySQL connection for a dynamic webpage

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i have a question about connecting my JSP webpage with a database.

I wrote a java class for the connection. If I test the connection with a extra java file (tester) in the same project it works fine. But when i try to use the same funktion in my jsp file ist doesnt connect and i get the massage: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver . First I thought its because I havent included the mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar file but than it wouldnt work with the java testfile in the same project  either.

And i have done the exact same imports in both files.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please include your code while asking a question on SO. That would be helpful for fellow programmers to know where the issue is and help you resolve them.

Comment: The JSP File is basically:

<%@page import="package"%>
<html>
<body>
<%SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my parameters");
conn.connect();
out.println(conn.isConnected());%>
...

SqlConnection is the Class and connect() is making a connection. isConnected() gives back a boolean, If the Database ist connected.

The workin Java tester:
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my parameters");
conn.connect();
System.out.println(conn.isConnected());
...

Comment: Your "tester" seems to be a stand-alone Java application, and will have a completely different class search path. You need to install the mysql JAR into either your web server, or your web application, in such a way that it can be found at runtime. It might be easier to advise if you explained what tools and web server you were using.